NameError: name 'options' is not defined
This is the project which I am trying to make
https://github.com/michaelkitas/Google-Maps-Leads-Scraper-Selenium/blob/master/readme.md 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from seleniumwire import webdriver as seleniumwire_webdriver
import time
import json
import re/Users/macbook/Desktop/Selenium Google Scraper
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
service = Service(
ChromeDriverManager().install()
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
service=service, options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options
)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
keyword =   "dumbster"


driver.get(f'https://www.google.com/maps/search/$(keyword)/')
Relevant log output
macbook-MacBook-Pro:Selenium Google Scraper macbook$ /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/macbook/Desktop/Selenium Google Scraper/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/macbook/Desktop/Selenium Google Scraper/main.py", line 18, in \<module\>
service=service, options=chrome_options, seleniumwire_options=options
^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'options' is not defined


You did not define the option varibale as the compiler tell you, you can see on your source repo that selenium take an option Parameter.
This is the example option that they give you.

options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': proxy,
        'https': proxy,
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}


You can modify it based on the result you except, all the other possible option configuration can be find on the selenium documentation
Also you imported Options which can help you to configure the chrome options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options() //This create an instance of an Options object
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions") //You can add or delete options

//Once you setup everything you can init your Webdriver
chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)


Similar problem here
